# How do I add List and separate string to the Database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have string question and list of options. 
I can add questions to the DB easily. The problem is, that I couldn't figure out the way of adding options of answers to that question.

ApplicationDbContext

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Option> Options { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Question.cs Model

```
    public class Question
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Option> Options { get; set; }
}
```

Option.cs Model

```
public class Option
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public List<Option> OptionList; //Couldn't figure out how to use it yet. 
}
```

QuestionController (Cut out the parts which are irrelevant to my problem)

```
public class QuestionController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public QuestionController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    [HttpGet("add")]
    public IActionResult AddQuestion()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost("add")]
    public IActionResult AddQuestion(Question model, Option option)
    {
        _context.Questions.Add(model);

        _context.Options.Add(option);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

AddQuestion view

```
<form asp-controller="Question" asp-action="AddQuestion" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
    <label asp-for="Content"></label>
    <input asp-for="Content" type="text" />
    <input asp-for="OptionList" type="text" />    
    <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I want to add options and after pressing submit, It must be added with the Question in DB.

Comment: Very unclear what your asking. Why does your `Option` class have a field `public List<Option> OptionList;`? And `<input asp-for="OptionList" type="text" />` makes no sense - you cannot bind an input to a collection (and in any case its a field - you can only bind properties).

Comment: I thought if I added OptionList, I would be able to add options to OptionList variable and then pass it to DB

Comment: If your view is for creating a new `Question` and collection of `Option` associated with that question, then you need to dynamically add inputs to your view for a new `Option` (which will bind to your `public virtual List<Option> Options { get; set; }` property. Suggest you start with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some options for dynamically adding collection items.

Comment: And you `Option` class needs a `QuestionId` property to associate it with a `Question` (a FK)

Comment: public class Option
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Question)]
    public int QuestionId {get; set;}    
    public virtual Question Question {get; set;}
}